# shell script to c converter

Tags: c, shell, converters

Does anyone know of any tool which can convert shell script '.sh' into a C file '.c' ?

Comment: How big is this shell script? Rather than spending effort trying to find a tool to convert it, is it not worthwhile just porting it to C?

Comment: It is large enough not to try manually but if cannot find a good way, I can start doing myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that any such tool exists. C and shell files are extremely different languages with completely different purposes, and there is no way to automatically convert one to the other.

Comment: Just make a shell implementation in a single .c file with `const char scripttext[] = "` at the end, and the tool is called `( cat shell.c "$1" ; echo '";' )>out.c`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but not getting what you want to convey. Can you please explain a little?

Comment: I mean find (or write) an implementation of the shell, and then embed your shell script as a constant string for the shell to run.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/sources/shc.html). Its not a compiler, but it does generate .c files during encoding/encrypting.

Otherwise, do it by hand. Learn to code in C and shell, then translate them yourself. that's the best way to do it.